# Finding the general formula of a sequence: $3,8,23,68,203,608,\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, closed-form, pattern-recognition

I have the following sequence : $$3,8,23,68,203,608,\cdots$$

I have found that definition by recurrence of this is 
$$a(n)=3a(n-1)-1$$ where $a_0=3$ as the first term.

I want to find the explicit formula for this sequence but I have no idea how to find it.

Comment: See [OEIS A$057198$](http://oeis.org/A057198).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that

> $$
> a_n-\frac12=3\left(a_{n-1}-\frac12\right),\qquad a_0=3,
> $$

then you may easily obtain an explicit formula for $a_n-\dfrac12$ thus an explicit formula for $a_n$.

*Addendum.* From $a_n=3a_{n-1}-1$, we are looking for a real number $\alpha$ such that 
$$
\color{red}{a_n}+\alpha=3\left(a_{n-1}+\alpha\right) \tag1
$$ then replacing $\color{red}{a_n}$ with $\color{red}{3a_{n-1}-1}$ and expanding $(1)$ gives
$$
\color{red}{3a_{n-1}-1}+\alpha=3a_{n-1}+3\alpha \tag2
$$ and $(2)$ rewrites $ -1+\alpha=3\alpha$ from which you deduce $\alpha=-\dfrac12$. The first term of the auxiliary sequence is $a_0-\dfrac12=3-\dfrac12=\dfrac52$. Thus from $(1)$ you get $a_n-\dfrac12=\dfrac52\times 3^n$.

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding how the formulae is obtained...

Comment: @Astroman Set $u_n=a_n-\dfrac12$. From $u_n=3u_{n-1}$, $u_0=5/2$ (this is a geometric sequence) you easily get $u_n=\dfrac52\times 3^n$ giving the formula$$ a_n=\dfrac52\times 3^n+\frac12.$$

Comment: I have two main questions : how did you know what to replace by what ? I mean, how did you get the 1/2 ? how am I supposed to know that ? (I have never done series ) Also, when you do replace all of the stuff, how did you solve for u0=5/2 ? (Im new to this)

Comment: Ok, I understand how you solved for u0, but I dn'T know how you figured all of this. Where does the 1/2 come from ?

Comment: @Astroman Please see my edit.

Comment: Ok, I like your explanation. Just a question though, is the strategy that you used something that is usually done in such problems ? Im kinda new to this domain so Ive never seen this type of way.

Comment: Ok, thank you again !

Comment: @Astroman You are welcome!

Comment: Sorry but I have a last question. How do you know that the first equation is equal ? I mean, it seems that you took out the minus one from it, wouldn't this make it an inequality ?

Comment: @Astroman I would help but I don't understand your question.

Comment: You have the equation (1) : a(n)+α=3(a(n−1)+α) How do you know that this equality is true when we know that our original equation as a minus 1 on the right side of the original recurrence equation ?

Comment: @Astroman Ok, it will always work fine. Considering *every* generic sequence with the form: $a_n=ca_{n-1}+d$ then you will always be able to find out such an $\alpha$ with the mentioned equality.

Comment: So you can just take out the minus one without any problem like you just did ? Also, here is my LAST question on this. The final equation that you obtained, did you just add the "n" as an exponent to the 3 like that because you knew that it was a geometric sequence, or you obtained it in a formal way ?

Comment: @Astroman The minus sign in front of $\alpha$ was not necessary, so you can take it out. Concerning the final equation, I used the fact that any sequence satisying $u_n=q\times u_{n-1}$ admits the formula $u_n=u_0 q^n$, (this is proved by induction).

Comment: While Im not completely sure why you think its not necessary. (For me, this would make it be an inequality) Im going to take it this way anyway. Ok thanks. ! !!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $a(n)= b(n)+cn+d$

$$b(n)+cn+d=3\{b(n-1)+c(n-1)+d\}-1$$

$$\iff b(n)+cn+d=3b(n-1)+3cn+3d-3c-1$$

Set $c=0,d=3d-3c-1$ to get $b(n)=3b(n-1)$